# The most productive regexp

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace, substr

I can get strings like these:

```
D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/some-module/node_modules/lodash/some-folder/lodash.js
D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/some-module/node_modules/colors/some-folder/colors.js
```

From any of these strings I have to get the next substrings:

```
D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/some-module/node_modules/lodash
D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/some-module/node_modules/colors
```

In other words I have to get substring which ends with module folder name.

I think to use regexp and I want to use them.
But I'm not good in regexp performance. I have to get these substrings as fast as possible. Could you, please, offer me the most fast regexp? Or maybe there is another faster way to get these substrings?

Comment: If the first part of the path, D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/some-module/node_modules, is a constant, _and_ you only need to fetch one word after that, you don't have to use regexes.

Comment: No, it is not constant, there can be 
D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/first-some-module/node_modules/
instead of D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/some-module/node_modules/

Comment: Confused by both the down votes and the close vote. This question is neither not useful, nor does it fit the "debugging help" close reason. Yes, I know that no-one has to answer for or explain either close votes or down votes, but guys, it could make sense to at least understand what they are supposed to mean before you exercise them.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/.*?node_modules(?!.*node_modules)\/[^/]*/
```

This says to find the `node_modules` string which **is not followed** (negative look-ahead) by any other `node_modules`, in other words the last one, then take the following segment up to the forward slash.

```
var s = "D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/some-module/node_modules/lodash/some-folder/lodash.js"
var r = /.*node_modules(?!.*node_modules)\/[^/]*/;

> s.match(r)
< ["D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/some-module/node_modules/lodash"]
```

Comment: node_modules folders can be in string many times. will your regexp work or it works only for strings which have node_modules two times only? and thank you!

Comment: Any number of times.